# Could not create an instance of ViewModelLocator whenever an instance of a model in a different assembly is initialized

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, entity-framework-4, mvvm-light

It is my first time posting something here in StackOverflow (it helped me a lot in the past though) and usually I don't even have to post a question because my supposed question was answered already. But this one I can't really find a proper explanation.

So I was tinkering with C#, Entity Framework 4, WPF, and MVVM Light. I already made an assembly that serves as a library for various Models, Views, and ViewModels, serving a specific purpose.

Now I'm making another assembly that would be for a different purpose. However there are some required methods and views that were already made available in the first assembly. So I thought I'm going to add a reference of the first assembly to the second assembly, then create an instance of the Model from the first assembly to either the Model or the ViewModel of the second assembly.

Everything were built without errors. But when I checked the design view of a View in the second assembly, this section has jagged underline:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and when you look at the design view, there's an error written at a top bar with the text:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Powell.Materials.Common.ViewModel.MaterialsViewViewModel.SetupLists() in E:\Projects\Software\Powell Marketing\Powell\Powell\Materials\Powell.Materials.Common\ViewModel\MaterialsViewViewModel.cs:line 514
   at Powell.Materials.Common.ViewModel.MaterialsViewViewModel..ctor() in E:\Projects\Software\Powell Marketing\Powell\Powell\Materials\Powell.Materials.Common\ViewModel\MaterialsViewViewModel.cs:line 601
```

Did somebody ever encountered this type of error? Or is there a proper way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: Well could you post `MaterialsViewViewModel.SetupLists()` please? I'm pretty sure, that the error can be found there.

Comment: `private void SetupLists()
        {
            Retrieve retrieve = new Retrieve(secretKey, IDUser, connectionName);

            unitListProperty = retrieve.RetrieveUnits();
            matlTypeProperty = retrieve.RetrieveMaterialTypes();
            supplierListProperty = retrieve.RetrieveSuppliers();
        }`

It calls a method within its own Model, which communicates with the Model from the referenced assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in the code I see 4 possible sources for a `NullReferenceException`.

- `secretKey`
- `IDUser`
- `connectionName`
- `retrieve` (although this might be correctly instantiated)

I've no idea where the first three come from. So check their values. I'm pretty sure that one of them is `null`. If all three are instantiated correctly, check the last one.

Comment: They're immediately instantiated whenever the program runs. But now that you've mentioned it, I guess I should declare a default value for each. Thanks a lot :D